# Disable default-filters on specific route - Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using Spring Cloud Gateway, and I have a use-case where I need to skip `default-filters` for a specific route.

The [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#default-filters) does not say anything about this option, is there any way to achieve it?

I cannot find any clues in the source code either.

Comment: current there is no way to disable default-filters on specific route,you can create a issue about this.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73066599/spring-cloud-gateway-circuit-breaker-default-and-specific