# Spring Cloud Gateway Circuit Breaker: Default and Specific

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Boot application with Spring Cloud Gateway using Resilience4j for circuit breaker:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j'
```

Currently I have the following routes:

```
  routes:
    - id: swapi-planets
      uri: https://swapi.devs/api/planets/
      predicates:
        - Path=/api/planets/**
      filters:
        - name: CircuitBreaker
          args:
            fallbackUri: https://swapi.dev/api/species/
    - id: swapi-species
      uri: https://swapi.dev/api/species/
      predicates:
        - Path=/api/species/**
  default-filters:
    - name: CircuitBreaker
      args:
        name: myCircuitBreaker
```

When I do a call to swapi-planets route I receive the following return from myCircuitBreaker:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-07-21T12:48:59.402+00:00",
    "path": "/api/planets",
    "status": 504,
    "error": "Gateway Timeout",
    "requestId": "8a8cdca2-1"
}
```

Is there a way to ignore default circuit breaker filter when the route already have a specific circuit breaker? In this case swapi-planets has a fallbackUri.

Comment: No - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/2056#issuecomment-736151857